# SQL query using IN with a list very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to optimize a query done like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable 
WHERE 
indexed_field IN ('v1', 'v2', ..., 'v2000')
AND NOT regular_field='something'
AND other_regular_field='something_else';
```

This query "works". The problem is that it is extremely slow (1min+). I thought that using the `IN` expression would be fine using a defined list, but it is turning out to not be that fine.

I'm using Postgresql 9.6.

My table has 310K.

The query expl:

```
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=396158.70..396158.71 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=8630.558..8630.559 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..396156.77 rows=772 width=0) (actual time=7853.840..8630.478 rows=916 loops=1)
        Filter: (((non_indexed_field)::text <> 'value1'::text) AND ((non_indexed_field)::text = 'value2'::text) AND ((indexed_field)::text = ANY ('{lots and lots of values....}'::text[])))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 306768
Planning time: 2.543 ms

Execution time: 8630.770 ms
```

With analyze, buffers:

```
Aggregate  (cost=396158.70..396158.71 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=9278.560..9278.560 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=14244
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..396156.77 rows=772 width=0) (actual time=8584.520..9278.431 rows=916 loops=1)
         Filter: (((non_indexed_field)::text <> 'value1'::text) AND ((non_indexed_field)::text = 'value2'::text) AND ((indexed_field)::text = ANY ('{lots and lots of values}'::text[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 306768
         Buffers: shared hit=14244
 Planning time: 1.293 ms
 Execution time: 9278.646 ms
(8 rows)
```

Comment: How many record exist in this table?
Can you please generate explain for this query and add here?

Comment: Around 310k records. Ok, I'm running the explain and I'll post here. Will take a moment..

Comment: 310k  records should bot be a Problem. More than 8 million should be Problem

Comment: If you have any join conditions in your Sql query then check that join  condition

Comment: There is no joins for this query. They query is exactly like I posted. I just changed the names to make it more clear (like show that the field is really indexed)

Comment: did you try with exists clause?

Comment: I did not try the exists clause

Comment: Can you run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` so that we can see how many blocks are processed?

Comment: Suggestion: I assume the `indexed_field` have some versions data and it contain `v+someNumber`, if thats the case then remove the v part from your data and convert that column into an integer, which is faster than string to compare, and search like `In (1,2,.....,2000)`. Also if the search data will always be in an order like ascending, then query like this  `where indexed_field between 1 and 2000` into a sub query as explained in the swissben answer

Comment: @Bsienn, those are good suggestions. I took the value from a spreedsheet. I might convert and do this in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very often joining to a a `VALUES` clause is more efficient:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM mytable 
  JOIN (
     values ('v1'), ('v2'), (...), ('v2000')
  ) as lookup(value) on lookup.value = mytable.some_column
WHERE NOT other_column = 'something'
AND another_column = 'something_else';
```

Pay attention to the format of the "list". In the `values` clause, each value needs to be enclosed in parentheses. `('v1'), ('v2'), ...` instead of `('v1', 'v2', ...)`

Online example: http://rextester.com/UUWVG71217

---

Note that if the column you compare the values to really is a number (e.g. integer), you should **not** specify the values using single quotes, e.g. `values (1),(2),(3),...(2000)`

Comment: Ok, this returned a much faster result. Instead of taking 10s for 1000 valus in the list, it returned in .4s! I didn't pay attention at first to the parenthesis around each individual value from the list

Comment: is there a place I could learn this kind of optimization? I've never seen/heard of joins making a query be more efficient. It is usually the other way around.

Comment: why `values` is more efficient than `in/any`? If the matched column is an index, I can understand. Otherwise, I do not have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

My simple suggestion you have to create indexes on these three fields you are using here

indexed_field 
regular_field
other_regular_field

as db search engine looking into table for all these three fields and if there is no index it goes to full table scan. Now you have vert small amount of data so it comes back in just 1+ minute, think if it is 4-5 million rows, and it would take hour. Index 3 fields and see the difference. Dont worry index will not hurt in any way.

Comment: I can't index all fields of my table. The non-index fields are variable.

Answer (score -1):

I'd rather recommend to use sub-selects (sub-queries) to pre-select the smaller set of data, e.g.:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM 
(SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE indexed_field IN ('v1', 'v2', ..., 'v2000')) t
WHERE NOT t.regular_field='something'
AND t.other_regular_field='something_else';
```

Comment: That won't change anything

Comment: Like @a_horse_with_no_name said, this returned the same result with the same execution time