# What is the most performant way to rewrite a large IN clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm, sql-in

I wrote an API using go and gorm that runs calculations on our database and returns the results.

I just hit the parameter limit for an `IN` condition when using an aggregate. Example query:

```
SELECT SUM(total_amount) from Table where user_id in(...70k parameters) group by user_id
```

One of my current edge cases has > 65535 user ids so my Postgres client is throwing an error:

> ```
> got 66037 parameters but PostgreSQL only supports 65535 parameters
> ```

I'm not sure what the best way to approach this is. One that will handle the large amount of parameters for this edge case while not affecting my typical use case. Do I chunk the ids and iterate through multiple queries storing it in memory until I have all the data I need? Use `ANY(VALUES)`...

Obviously from the query I have very limited knowledge of Postgres so any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: you create a table with the user_id you need and do a left join

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace `user_id IN (value [, ...])` with one of:

```
user_id IN (subquery)
user_id = ANY (subquery)
user_id = ANY (array expression)
```

Neither subqueries nor arrays exhibit the same limitation. The shortest input syntax would be:

```
user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::int[])  -- make array type match type of user_id
```

Details and more options:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

**Or** you might create a (temporary) table `tmp_usr(user_id int)`, import to it, maybe with SQL `COPY` or psql `\copy` instead of `INSERT` for best performance with **big sets** and then *join* to the table like:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(total_amount)
FROM   tbl
JOIN   tmp_usr USING (user_id)
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

BTW, you'll want to include `user_id` in the `SELECT` list to identify sums.

Comment: Joining to a values clause instead of an `IN` is another option that sometimes is faster as well. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387410)

Comment: Yes, a `VALUES` expression is one form of a subquery, and this is typically faster for big sets. A variation on the theme: pass an array and `unnest` in a subquery. Info and link to more for each in the linked answer above.